# How to check missing timestamp in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my SQL database (MySql), I want to record the price history of an asset.

I have a table with a timestamp as a primary key and price as the value. It has only two column `timestamp / price`
There should be one price point per second recorded.

Sometimes, there are missing price points. (When the server goes down)

Here is an example of the timestamp column.

```
**timestamp**
1581431400
1581431401
1581431402
1581431403
1581431405
1581431406 //missing 4 rows price points after this 
1581431410 
1581431411
1581431412
1581431413
1581431414
1581431415 //missing 3 rows price points after this 
1581431418
1581431419
1581431420
```

Given two timestamps, how to run a SQL query that will fetch the timestamp ranges where the data exists **without querying the entire database**?

For example, I let's say the two timestamp in UNIX are `1` and `2000000000`
What is the SQL query I should run to return the following ranges:

```
[
[1581431400,1581431406],
[1581431410,1581431415],
[1581431418,1581431420]
]
```

Comment: there is also one row missing after 1581431403 ?

Comment: Please add your mysql version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use window functions:

```
select min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select timestamp, row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (timestamp - seqnum);
```

I'm not sure what "without querying the entire database?" is supposed to mean.  This reads the *table* -- as any such query would need to -- but does not need to query anything else in the database.

This illustrates what happens:

```
timestamp    seqnum    diff
1581431400     1       1581431399
1581431401     2       1581431399
1581431402     3       1581431399
1581431403     4       1581431399
1581431405     5       1581431400
1581431406     6       1581431400
1581431410     7       1581431403 
1581431411     8       1581431403
```

The last column is identifying adjacent timestamps that differ by "1".  That is what is aggregated in the outer query.

Comment: does this work on mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.14 ? if not, what is the version it requires?

Comment: @TSR . . . No.  It requires MSQL 8+.

Comment: This work great! Can you please explain a little bit ? Especially this part:  group by (timestamp - seqnum); ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer (Hack). You can use a query like this.

```
SELECT CONCAT( '[',GROUP_CONCAT('\n',
      '[', res.missing_from, '],'
     ,'[', res.missing_to -1,']') , '\n]') AS missing
FROM (
    SELECT m.ts+1 AS missing_from,
    (SELECT ts FROM mytable WHERE ts > m.ts ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1 ) as missing_to
    FROM mytable m
    LEFT JOIN mytable mf ON m.ts+1 = mf.ts
    WHERE
        mf.ts IS NULL
) AS res
WHERE res.missing_to - res.missing_from > 0;
```

**SAMPLE**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mytable;
+------------+
| ts         |
+------------+
| 1581431400 |
| 1581431401 |
| 1581431402 |
| 1581431403 |
| 1581431405 |
| 1581431406 |
| 1581431410 |
| 1581431411 |
| 1581431412 |
| 1581431413 |
| 1581431414 |
| 1581431415 |
| 1581431418 |
| 1581431419 |
| 1581431420 |
+------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**TEST**

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT( '[',GROUP_CONCAT('\n',
      '[', res.missing_from, '],'
     ,'[', res.missing_to -1,']') , '\n]') AS missing
FROM (
    SELECT m.ts+1 AS missing_from,
    (SELECT ts FROM mytable WHERE ts > m.ts ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1 ) as missing_to
    FROM mytable m
    LEFT JOIN mytable mf ON m.ts+1 = mf.ts
    WHERE
        mf.ts IS NULL
) AS res
WHERE res.missing_to - res.missing_from > 0;


+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| missing                                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [
[1581431404],[1581431404],
[1581431407],[1581431409],
[1581431416],[1581431417]
] |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: This is a smart hack